# How to deal with unicode while exporting data in csv format using fputcsv in php?

Tags: php, csv, unicode, utf-8

I have following code to export data in csv format. It works fine in normal text, but didnot work if unicode exists means exported text are illegible even with the option of charset=utf-8, what should i do right here

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=magazine_subscribers'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv');
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Customer Id', 'Name', 'Company','Subscription Type','Address 1','Postal Code','City','Email','mobile','note','Invoice Receiver','Invoice Email','Invoice address','Invoice city','Invoice Postal Code'));

foreach($subscribers as $subscriber)
{
    fputcsv($output,array($subscriber->customer_id,$subscriber->name,$subscriber->company,$subscriber->subscription_type,$subscriber->address_1,$subscriber->postal_code,$subscriber->city,$subscriber->email,$subscriber->mobile,$subscriber->note,$subscriber->invoice_receiver,$subscriber->invoice_email,$subscriber->invoice_address,$subscriber->invoice_city,$subscriber->invoice_zip));
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');` is simply telling a __web browser__ what charset the downloaded file is.... what application are you using to open this file once it's been sent to the browser?

Comment: MsExcel in OSX, @Mark Baker

Comment: Then it's MS Excel that's having problems recognising the file as UTF-8.... try adding a UTF-8 BOM header as the first few bytes of your file

Comment: @Mark Baker thanks for your effort but did not work

Comment: I did mean the file you're sending to the browser (`php://output`) just to clarify what I meant